# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method FromNews

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

First I will explain what I am trying to do.

I am trying to grab a list of news articles from my entity framework and convert them to another object. However I get this exception:

`System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Database.Entity.DataTransferObjects.NewsObject FromNews(Database.Entity.News)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

This is my code:

`IEnumerable<NewsObject> news_articles = context.GetLatestNews(0);`

```
    public IEnumerable<NewsObject> GetLatestNews(int start)
    {
        IQueryable<NewsObject> latest_news = context.News.Where(news => news.Published).Select(articles => NewsObject.FromNews(articles));
        IEnumerable<NewsObject> latest_news_ordered = latest_news.OrderByDescending(news => news.PublishedDate).Skip(start).Take(5);
        return latest_news_ordered;
    }
```

This is my FromNews part:

```
    public static NewsObject FromNews(News news)
    {
        return new NewsObject
        {
            Id = news.Id,
            Permalink = news.Permalink,
            Subject = news.Subject,
            Summary = news.Summary,
            Content = news.Content,
            Thumbnail = news.Thumbnail,
            Published = news.Published,
            PublishedDate = news.PublishedDate,
            PublishedBy = news.PublishedBy,
            CategoryId = news.CategoryId,
            Publisher = MemberObject.FromMember(news.Publisher),
            Category = CategoryObject.FromCategory(news.Category)
        };
    }
```

I read it's a problem with the way LINQ is built/used but none of them provided a work around for what I am doing. I am trying to make code tiday :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you do it this way:

```
public IEnumerable<NewsObject> GetLatestNews(int start)
{
    IQueryable<NewsObject> latest_news = context.News
        .Where(news => news.Published)
        .ToList()
        .Select(articles => NewsObject.FromNews(articles));
    IEnumerable<NewsObject> latest_news_ordered = latest_news
        .OrderByDescending(news => news.PublishedDate)
        .Skip(start).Take(5)
        .AsEnumerable();
    return latest_news_ordered;
}
```

By invoking ToList() on your query, EF hits the db and no longer builds expression trees into your iqueryable. After the query is executed, it will pass to your FromNews method.

**Update**

To address the Skip and Take excerpts from comments, something like this could be done:

```
public IEnumerable<NewsObject> GetLatestNews(int start)
{
    IQueryable<NewsObject> latest_news = context.News
        .Where(news => news.Published)
        .OrderByDescending(news => news.PublishedDate)
        .Skip(start)
        .Take(5)
        .ToList()
        .Select(articles => NewsObject.FromNews(articles))
        .ToList(); // see Daniel Hilgarth's answer also
    IEnumerable<NewsObject> latest_news_ordered = latest_news
        .AsEnumerable();
    return latest_news_ordered;
}
```

**Reply to comments**

Sorry I didn't realize you were converting from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`. You can do this by calling the `.AsEnumerable()` method on the `IQueryable` instance. I have updated the code posted.

I have also updated the code to invoke `.Skip` and `.Take` before `.OrderByDescending`. This makes sense because if you skip and take before ordering, your results will only be ordered within the 5 records you take. You need to order, then skip and take.

Also see [Daniel Hilgarth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769094/304832) regarding deferred execution on the `.Select` method.

Comment: I would move the call to ToList() after Take(5)

Comment: @AdrianIftode: This wouldn't work. The `Select` with the unsupported method must come after the `ToList`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I mean to materialize the query after take(5), sure this means removing the unsupported projection. I'm thinking that the News table might have 1 billion rows.. what do we do with all?

Comment: Thanks but I get this error when trying your way: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Database.Entity.DataTransferObjects.NewsObject>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Database.Entity.DataTransferObjects.NewsObject>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @SHTester replace IQueryable<T> with var

Comment: This error now, not sure why you cant skip before ordering? `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.`

Comment: @SHTester, I have updated my answer. You need to convert the IQueryable to IEnumerable by invoking `.AsEnumerable()`. You also do need to apply ordering before skip and take.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will give your answer the tick :)

Answer (score 2):

"LINQ to EF" is working with expression trees. The code inside the LINQ query is not really executed but parsed and translated to SQL.

Because of this, not all methods can be used inside a LINQ query, especially user defined methods. They are simply unknown by the code that creates the SQL statement from the expression tree.

One way would be to put a `ToList()` before the `Select`. This way, the part in `Select` no longer is "LINQ to EF" but LINQ to Objects which hasn't these restrictions.
But beware: This will also move the calls to `Skip` and `Take` to LINQ to Objects and thus to the memory of your application, meaning that all objects that match your `Where` clause are fetched from the database, not only the 5 you want to return.

Because of all this, I would change the query to this:

```
return context.News.Where(news => news.Published)
              .OrderByDescending(news => news.PublishedDate)
              .Skip(start).Take(5)
              .ToList()
              .Select(articles => NewsObject.FromNews(articles))
              .ToList();
```

Please note one important thing: There are two calls to `ToList()` in this code. The first one is to change the code to LINQ to Objects and the second is to execute the code in the `Select`. Because LINQ uses deferred execution, the `Select` part would be executed each time you enumerate the result of this method, leading to new objects each time.